# Is there a way to assign unique IDs to createElement objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, unique-id

I have a button when pressed creates new input bars and I would like those input bars to have unique ids, for example - textBar1, textBar2, textBar3 and so on.

I tried creating a variable outside of the function that has the value 0 and then inside the function add the value with +1 for each time the function runs but that doesn't work but instead it assigns the id textBar0 to every element that is created.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

**HTML**

```
<label for='ingredient'></label>
<input id="textBar" class="textBar" type="name" name="ingredient">

<div id="textBarPosition"></div>
<div id="addRemoveContainer">

<input id="addBar" type="button" value="Add Ingredient">
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
   var counter = 0;
function createSector() {
  var input = document.createElement('input'); 
  input.setAttribute("id", 'textBar' + counter +1);
  input.type = 'text';
  input.name = 'name[]';
  return input;
counter = 1;

}


var form = document.getElementById('textBarPosition');
document.getElementById('addBar').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // step 1: create element and set opacity to 0.
    var selector = $(createSector());
    selector.fadeIn();

   // step 2: append it to its parent.
    $(form).append(selector);

    $('#removeBar').click(function(){
        $("input:last-child").remove(".textBar");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is becaus you're not reassinging the changed value to `counter`. 
Use `counter+=1` instead or just `counter++`

```
input.setAttribute("id", 'textBar' + counter++); // now it should work
```

What you were doing before was always add `1` to `0`

Answer (score 3):

Best way is to use [_.uniqueId](http://underscorejs.org/#uniqueId).

Generate a globally-unique id for client-side models or DOM elements that need one. If prefix is passed, the id will be appended to it.

```
_.uniqueId('contact_');
=> 'contact_104'
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Okay, I will add an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Math.random` like this:

```
input.setAttribute("id", 'textBar_' + Math.random().toString(36));
```

It is my understanding that when you first call `Math.random` it generates a sequence of unique random numbers between 0 and 1 using the current time in milliseconds as a seed then returns the first one. Subsequent calls will move through the generated sequence of numbers, returning them one at a time, giving you the ability to generate random unique strings for element IDs.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Code -

```
  var counter = 0;
function createSector() {
  var input = document.createElement('input'); 
  input.setAttribute("id", 'textBar' + counter);
  input.type = 'text';
  input.name = 'name[]';
  return input;


}

var form = document.getElementById('textBarPosition');
document.getElementById('addBar').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // step 1: create element and set opacity to 0.
    var selector = $(createSector());
    counter++;
    selector.fadeIn();

   // step 2: append it to its parent.
    $(form).append(selector);

    $('#removeBar').click(function(){
        $("input:last-child").remove(".textBar");
    });
});
```

Working JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/mtafre04/

Comment: This assigns the value 'textBar0' to id of first dynamically created input box, so put it below var selector. First time when 'Add Ingredient' is clicked it takes counter value 0 and assigns id 'textBar0' to first input box and then it increments this value by 1 each time button is clicked (so second input box gets id 'textBar1', third - 'textBar2' and so on). If you place counter++ above var selector it will start assigning value to input box from 'textBar1' (first input box will get id 'textBar1', second -'textBar2', third -'textBar3' and so on).